# OpenGL Shader stretches geomatry

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I created a simple program that renders a quad

**Initialize:**

```
Math::float3 vertices[4];
vertices[0] = Math::float3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f);
vertices[1] = Math::float3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f);
vertices[2] = Math::float3(0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f);
vertices[3] = Math::float3(0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f);

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

unsigned int indices[] = {
               0, 1, 2,
               2, 3, 0
            };

glGenBuffers(1, &IBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

**Rendering:**

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Math::float3), 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Which renders a perfectly square quad.

I continued by adding a vertex shader program:

**Vertex shader**

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(Position.x, Position.y, Position.z, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
   FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And if I run my program again, the quad seems to be stretched to about twice its size on x axis, and stretched slightly on the Y.

**Without shaders**

[image: without shaders]

**With shaders**

[image: with shader]

Any idea on what could be causing this? If you need more code snippets or additional info, please let me know :)

**Update**

Some extra code.

**Opening the window / reshape**

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
glutInitWindowSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
glutCreateWindow(TITLE);
```

...

```
if(_h == 0) _h = 1;
float ratio = 1.0f * _w / _h;
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, _w, _h);
gluPerspective(45.0f, ratio, 1, 1000);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

**Update 2**

My problem sadly still persists, some extra info here:

My geomatry:

```
Math::float3 vertices[4];
vertices[0] = Math::float3(-0.5, -0.5f, -1.0f);
vertices[1] = Math::float3(0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f);
vertices[2] = Math::float3(0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f);
vertices[3] = Math::float3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f);

unsigned int indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 };
```

**My vertex shader**

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = MVP * vec4(Position.x, Position.y, Position.z, 1.0);
}
```

**Setup view**

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

#define FOV 60.0f
#define RATIO 1.0f * SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT
#define ZNEAR 1.0f
#define ZFAR 1000.0f

if(_h == 0) _h = 1;
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, _w, _h);
gluPerspective(FOV, RATIO, ZNEAR, ZFAR);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

**Initialize**

```
Math::float3 vertices[4];
vertices[0] = Math::float3(-0.5, -0.5f, -1.0f);
vertices[1] = Math::float3(0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f);
vertices[2] = Math::float3(0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f);
vertices[3] = Math::float3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f);

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices,      GL_STATIC_DRAW);

unsigned int indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 };

glGenBuffers(1, &IBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

sl = new Loader::ShaderLoader();
sl->Initialize();
sl->AddShader("data/shaders/shader.vs", VERTEX_SHADER);
sl->AddShader("data/shaders/shader.fs", FRAGMENT_SHADER);

sl->CompileShaders();
```

**Render**

```
MVP = glGetUniformLocation(sl->GetShaderProgram(), "MVP");

float m[16];

f -= 0.01f;

m[0] = 1.0f;
m[1] = 0.0f;
m[2] = 0.0f;
m[3] = 0.0f;

m[4] = 0.0f;
m[5] = 1.0f;
m[6] = 0.0f;
m[7] = 0.0f;

m[8] = 0.0f;
m[9] = 0.0f;
m[10] = 1.0f;
m[11] = 0.0f;

m[12] = 0.0f;
m[13] = 0.0f;
m[14] = 0.0f;
m[15] = 1.0f;

glUniformMatrix4fv(MVP, 1, GL_TRUE, m);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

I've also printed the value for MVP per render call, and it's always 0 for some reason.

Again, any additional tips are welcome, thanks!

Comment: I don't see the code that initializes your viewport (`glViewport` call) - can you double-check that it is initialized correctly to the window dimensions?

Comment: Updated my post with my initialization code :)

Comment: Added another update with how I set up my geomatry and FOV

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a non-identity transformation chain (non-identity projection and/or modelview matrix) set up with the fixed function. When using shaders the fixed function matrices are not used, which may explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by different approach to PVM (projection-view-model) matrix in OpenGL. In fixed pipeline, this matrix was defined by functions glMatrixMode.

When shaders are used, these matrices are usually sent to vertex shader as uniform and handled here.

Your vertex shader then will be something like this:

```
in vec3 Position;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Model;

void main(){
    gl_Position = Projection * View * Model * vec4(Position.x, Position.y, Position.z, 1.0);
}
```

This should provide some more info about these three matrices: [Tutorial 3 matrices](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/)

Comment: Especially for your problem, you need at least Projection matrix, which deform object according to size of window.

Comment: Thank you this looks very helpful! This part is indeed missing from my vertex shader. Will look into that as soon as I have a chance :)

Comment: I now tried with an identity matrix, and even that is stretched :/

Comment: Yeah, because you used identity matrix. which means that no vector was modified in any way. If you try to multiply it, you will see that there is no modification. In that tutorial, I posted, there is written something about projection matrix.

Comment: There is math behind [projection matrices.](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) For 2D, you can use Orthographic, which is described lower at the page.

Comment: Aaaah yes ofcourse, with an identity matrix it also doesn't take aspect ratio in account then. Really working on my math skills haha :P thanks for the reply! Will dive into the tutorial again when I have access to my pc!